# iMac Speakers don't work

Tags: imac, audio, speakers

Looking for a little bit help here. I've searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer. My 2013 27" iMac doesn't play sound with the speakers (movies, youtube, itunes, etc..) but when I go to "Preferences" and "audio" and click on any of the sound effects there, the effects are played trough the speakers. I can't turn off the "mute" option on that preference panel. Any idea how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: does your Mute on the keyboard works ? or is it stuck

Comment: Yes, all the keys related to sound work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Finder Go to `/Library/Preferences/Audio`

and delete those files from there (2 or 3 files)

Do not worry OS will recreate them.

Empty your trash

Restart

Comment: Thanks a lot men!! That did the trick! Works great now! Thanks!!

Comment: you are welcome. Another happy person !

Comment: This is an answer that is SO useful for many things.

Comment: @SolarMike let me give you some points for that

Comment: @Buscar웃 can we organise a post that stays at the top like a faq that gives a list of "solutions" starting with clearing prefs and expanding to more serious moves...

Comment: @SolarMike good suggestion, usually this side only likes one question and one answer type

Answer (score 0):

Select the output tab and see if you have something besides the internal speakers selected

Comment: No, I only have there "Internal speakers" "built-in" You can check the image I've added to the OP.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yep, done that several times.